# Why does QuasiNewton take more number of iterations than Newton method?

Tags: optimization

Let's say we have a function f(x) = ∑<sub>k=1</sub><sup>N</sup> x<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>.

Why does Quasi Newton take more steps than Newton? Is it because Quasi Newton involves approximation of second derivative which is not that accurate and hence uses some iteration to come to minimal value of function?

Comment: In this case, when your function is a positive definite quadratic function, Newton's method solves it in a single step. So that's going to be hard to beat. Newton does not beat quasi-newton in general, particularly on nonconvex functions (but even not always on convex ones).

Comment: @JohnMadden:  This looks like an answer, can you make it into one?